# HTML- dreamweaver how to give a single cell 3 sides of borders, not every side

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I want to make a table like this shown in HTML.

[image]

Now I have used dreamweaver CS6 to draw a table by inserting a table and merging some cells. Dreamweaver could generate the code automatically. I want to give border to 3 sides (not 4 sides) of a merged cell only like shown in the picture with a highlighted green cycle. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 3 borders? I only have CS6 and I assume your using CC, so I'll just give you the CSS and you can insert it.

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
td {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
th {
  border: 2px dashed green;
}
.specCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>3 Borders</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="specCell">3 Border TH</th>
      <th>TH</th>
      <th>TH</th>
      <th>TH</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td class="specCell">3 Border TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td class="specCell">3 Border TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td class="specCell">3 Border TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="specCell">3 Border TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you a lot. But actually everything is a big table, I only want to give 3 borders to a single cell. But if I use CSS, it will give borders to all tables.

Comment: @Elena Sorry reread your question, updated to what you hopefully meant.

Comment: hi, I posted a question on the following link. It is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081750/html-in-chrome-shows-an-additional-border-that-not-shown-in-ie. Hope you could help answer, thanks in advance.