# HTML in Chrome shows an additional border that not shown in IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Hi I have a problem showing in Google Chrome.There is additional line showing in Google chrome, but in IE and in Dreamweaver, there is no such line.
The idea is to give a cell 3 borders. I have highlighted with  in the snippet where this problem code is.

Thanks for your help in advance.

[image]

**HTML snippet**

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ArrowCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>resultw</b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" class="ArrowCell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> sdf</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>resut1</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2">&larr;</td>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="7" class="ArrowCell">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> 345</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>result</b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"> sf</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>rest</b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="5" class="ArrowCell">&nbsp;</td>  <If I remove the class="", then the whole line will disaapear-->

            <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0">sfd</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#C4E1FF"><b>result 2</b></td>
            <td rowspan="2">&larr;</td>
            <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="5" style="border-left-color:#FFF">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0">4356 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#DFFFDF"><b>resultw</b></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>  
            <td bgcolor="#C4E1FF">avv</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

**One solution tried that doesn't work**

Add this class to the cell that with additional line.

```
.ArrowLeft {
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Although OP's problem may seem specialized, this could apply to anyone that has experienced a stubborn border on a table and can't seem to get rid of it.

Add the following to the table:

```
Table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

This is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/0Leqah5r

Try:

```
.ArrowCell {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-left:  1px solid red;
    border-bottom:  1px solid red;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
}
```

I don't see that extra line in Chrome PC, but when I inspect it with devtools, computed style for `.ArrowCell` is reported as `0.8px solid black;` so I'm guessing that changing it's color to transparent should work.

I just thought of another possibility to your issue. Double check and see if your rowspans might be conflicting by crossing into each other.

Another possible fix is to change `border-collapse: separate;` to `border-collapse: collapse;` and maybe `border-spacing: 0` as well.

Comment: Thanks@zer00ne, I tried this solution, it still shows that line. Because I used Python to run this code, maybe it is the reason why shows this line. If I just use dreamweaver and google chrome, it doesn't show this line as well. I have tried another solution: to make the left border of the cell with that additional line white. It still not works. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Elena I justed posted at the same time you did, see update.

Comment: Hi@zer00ne, I checked the rowspans already, there is no confliction. Because it is done by dreamweaver table function, so less error regarding that. I tried to inspect the element on Google Chrome/styles, doesn't see if that cell is bordered or not. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Hi@zer00ne, I tried to change the border collapse and spacing, still not work. Please see updated code above. I want to give that cell a left border with white color so as to cover that black line. Still not work, do you think if I can cover it in some way?

Comment: @Elena do you have that particular chart online so I can inspect it with devtools? As far as color goes, try `border-left: 0 none transparent !important;`

Comment: and I tried "border-left: 2px solid white !important;" and "border-left: 0 none transparent !important;", it is still not covering that black line....

Comment: Unfortunately, no I never have. I'm just a front-end developer, my company's back-end (PostgreSQL/RoR) is in another country. If I ever have the time Python is what I am going to learn next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96976/discussion-between-elena-and-zer00ne).